# IIS return error 403 on port 80

Tags: iis-7.5, hosting, windows-server-2008, access-denied

i set up hosting with windows 2008 and use websitepanel for control panel host(manage websites). in internal network all website with domain Easily open but in external network returned error "403 Access Denied" that Observable with firebug and in html page see only 0 (zero).
by the way when i configure website on other port(for example 8080) website in external network is open.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please see your firewall and check whether port 80 is open and also check the TCP port in the IIS website properties is set to 80